# Why will the notification icon dismiss after recreates in Android Studio?

Tags: android

The following code is a sample code about [Notifications](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/master/Notifications) in the project user-interface-samples.

*Image A* will be displayed when I launch *BIG_PICTURE_STYLE* notification, *Image B* will be displayed  when I click the earth image and the notification icon on top toolbar will dismiss.

1:  If I click "No" button on *Image A*，the notification icon on top toolbar will dismiss and this notification view will dismiss too.
I'm very strange the function `private void handleActionComment(CharSequence comment)` in *BigPictureSocialIntentService.java* has recreates the notification,  why will the notification icon dismiss?

2:  I modified *BigPictureSocialIntentService.java*, you can see *BigPictureSocialIntentService_Modified.jav*a, then I click "No" button on *Image A,* I find the notification icon dismiss, but the notification view keep display,you can see *Image C*, why?

BTW, I test it in API 30.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
 ...  
 private void generateBigPictureStyleNotification() {

        Log.d(TAG, "generateBigPictureStyleNotification()");

        MockDatabase.BigPictureStyleSocialAppData bigPictureStyleSocialAppData =
                MockDatabase.getBigPictureStyleData();        
        String notificationChannelId =
                NotificationUtil.createNotificationChannel(this, bigPictureStyleSocialAppData);
       
        BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                // Provides the bitmap for the BigPicture notification.
                .bigPicture(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                getResources(),
                                bigPictureStyleSocialAppData.getBigImage()))
                // Overrides ContentTitle in the big form of the template.
                .setBigContentTitle(bigPictureStyleSocialAppData.getBigContentTitle())
                // Summary line after the detail section in the big form of the template.
                .setSummaryText(bigPictureStyleSocialAppData.getSummaryText());

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, BigPictureSocialMainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);     
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(BigPictureSocialMainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(mainIntent);
      
        PendingIntent mainPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        mainIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        
        String replyLabel = getString(R.string.reply_label);
        RemoteInput remoteInput =
                new RemoteInput.Builder(BigPictureSocialIntentService.EXTRA_COMMENT)
                        .setLabel(replyLabel)
                        // List of quick response choices for any wearables paired with the phone
                        .setChoices(bigPictureStyleSocialAppData.getPossiblePostResponses())
                        .build();
   
        PendingIntent replyActionPendingIntent;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, BigPictureSocialIntentService.class);
            intent.setAction(BigPictureSocialIntentService.ACTION_COMMENT);
            replyActionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

        } else {
            replyActionPendingIntent = mainPendingIntent;
        }

        NotificationCompat.Action replyAction =
                new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                        R.drawable.ic_reply_white_18dp,
                        replyLabel,
                        replyActionPendingIntent)
                        .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                        .build();

     

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompatBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), notificationChannelId);

        GlobalNotificationBuilder.setNotificationCompatBuilderInstance(notificationCompatBuilder);

        notificationCompatBuilder
                .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                .setContentTitle(bigPictureStyleSocialAppData.getContentTitle())
                .setContentText(bigPictureStyleSocialAppData.getContentText())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_person_black_48dp))
                .setContentIntent(mainPendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setSubText(Integer.toString(1))
                .addAction(replyAction)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SOCIAL)
                .setPriority(bigPictureStyleSocialAppData.getPriority())
                .setVisibility(bigPictureStyleSocialAppData.getChannelLockscreenVisibility());

        for (String name : bigPictureStyleSocialAppData.getParticipants()) {
            notificationCompatBuilder.addPerson(name);
        }

        Notification notification = notificationCompatBuilder.build();
        mNotificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

   ...
}
```

**BigPictureSocialMainActivity.java**

```
public class BigPictureSocialMainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_big_picture_main);

        // Cancel Notification
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.cancel(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID);

        // TODO: Handle and display social post from your database
    }
}
```

**BigPictureSocialIntentService.java**

```
public class BigPictureSocialIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "BigPictureService";

    public static final String ACTION_COMMENT =
            "com.example.android.wearable.wear.wearnotifications.handlers.action.COMMENT";

    public static final String EXTRA_COMMENT =
            "com.example.android.wearable.wear.wearnotifications.handlers.extra.COMMENT";

    public BigPictureSocialIntentService() {
        super("BigPictureSocialIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {       
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_COMMENT.equals(action)) {
                handleActionComment(getMessage(intent));
            }
        }
    }

 
    private void handleActionComment(CharSequence comment) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleActionComment(): " + comment);

        if (comment != null) {

            // Retrieves NotificationCompat.Builder used to create initial Notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompatBuilder =
                    GlobalNotificationBuilder.getNotificationCompatBuilderInstance();

            // Recreate builder from persistent state if app process is killed
            if (notificationCompatBuilder == null) {
                // Note: New builder set globally in the method
                notificationCompatBuilder = recreateBuilderWithBigPictureStyle();
            }

            // Updates active Notification
            Notification updatedNotification = notificationCompatBuilder
                    // Adds a line and comment below content in Notification
                    .setRemoteInputHistory(new CharSequence[]{comment})
                    .build();

            // Pushes out the updated Notification
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat =
                    NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
            notificationManagerCompat.notify(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, updatedNotification);
        }
    }


    private CharSequence getMessage(Intent intent) {
        Bundle remoteInput = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent);
        if (remoteInput != null) {
            return remoteInput.getCharSequence(EXTRA_COMMENT);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * This recreates the notification from the persistent state in case the app process was killed.
     * It is basically the same code for creating the Notification from MainActivity.
     */
    private NotificationCompat.Builder recreateBuilderWithBigPictureStyle() {
         ...
    }
}
```

**BigPictureSocialIntentService_Modified.java**

```
public class BigPictureSocialIntentService extends IntentService {
    ....
    private void handleActionComment(CharSequence comment) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleActionComment(): " + comment);

        if (comment != null) {
           NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.cancel(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID);
        }
    }
}
```

**Image A**

[image]

**Image B**

[image]

**Image C**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reply action is meant to get user replies and display the reply to the user. so the Notification with reply action cannot be dismissed by you.

According to [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#reply-action):

> After you’ve processed the text, you must update the notification by calling NotificationManagerCompat.notify() with the same ID and tag (if used). This is necessary to hide direct reply UI and confirm to the user that their reply was received and processed correctly.

You must create another notification like last one and it should not have reply action to tell the user that his/her reply is received.

If you really want to dismiss the notification with the same ID and tag, you can create a normal notification and dismiss it immediately.